# Not seeing a clock cycle delay in Vivado simulation during a register/flipflop assignment

Tags: verilog, simulation, fpga, vivado, test-bench

I am trying to generate a pulse from a signal `ext_sample_clk`. My design currently has 2 clock signals, `clk` and `ext_sample_clk`, which I am generating through a testbench. The following is my simplified code. Besides this, I also have the `clk` and reset generation logic, which I have not shown for simplicity. I can share those if needed.

```
module tb;
reg clk;
reg rst;
reg ext_sample_clk;
reg ext_sample_clk_r1;
wire ext_sample_pulse_orig;

//clock gen logic
always 
begin
    clk = 1'b1; 
    #5; // 10 ns

    clk = 1'b0;
    #5;
end

// reset gen logic
initial 
begin 
    rst = 1;
    #(100);
    rst = 0;
end

// ext_sample_clk logic
always 
begin
    ext_sample_clk = 1'b1; 
    #50; 
    ext_sample_clk = 1'b0;
    #50; 
end

// register the ext_sample_clk logic, should infer a flip flop
always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (rst)
        ext_sample_clk_r1       <= 0;
    else
        ext_sample_clk_r1       <= ext_sample_clk; // lhs doesn't appear to be delayed by 1 clock cycle wrt to rhs
end     
assign ext_sample_pulse_orig   = ext_sample_clk        && !ext_sample_clk_r1; 

endmodule
```

I am expecting to see ext_sample_clk_r1 delayed by one clock pulse compared to ext_sample_clk. But the following is what I observe when I run a simulation on Vivado.
[image]

Can anyone explain why I am not seeing a clock cycle delay in ext_sample_clk_r1 with reference to ext_sample_clk. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want `ext_sample_clk_r1` and  `ext_sample_clk` to be synchronous to the same clock (`clk`), you need to drive them both off of `posedge clk`, using nonblocking assignments (`<=`):

```
initial begin 
    ext_sample_clk = 1'b1; 
    forever begin
        repeat (10) @(posedge clk);
        ext_sample_clk <= ~ext_sample_clk;
    end
end
```

Here is a running example on [edaplayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/9AF9).

Answer (score 1):

The most probably way of getting the results you see is by using a blocking assignment to `ext_sample_clk` instead of a non-blocking assignment. Your testbench needs to follow the same rules as if it were part of the design to avoid race conditions. Use a non-blocking assignment or have your testbench apply signals on the opposite edge.

Comment: I am trying to keep my code (besides the reset and clock generation) to be the same between the design and testbench. So could you explain in a bit more detail on how using a non-blocking assignment or having my testbench apply signals on the opposite edge solve my issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because the time that `ext_sample_clk` rises is in a race with the rising edge of `clk`  You don't know if the last `always` block executes before or after ext_sample_clk has been updated.